# how to loop rock paper scissors

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
print('Ви граєте у гру \'Камінь, ножниці, папір\' !')
choices = ['Камінь' , 'Папір' , 'Ножниці']


user_choice = input('Виберіть : Камінь, Ножниці або Папір : \nВаш вибір : ')
computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
print('Комп\'ютер вибрав : ' + computer_choice)

computer_score = 0
user_score = 0 

game = False
while game == False:


 if user_choice == 'Камінь' and computer_choice == 'Папір':
  computer_score += 1
  print('Ви програли !')

 elif user_choice == 'Камінь' and computer_choice == 'Ножниці':
  user_score += 1
  print('Ви перемогли !')

 elif user_choice == 'Папір' and computer_choice == 'Ножниці':
  computer_score += 1
  print('Ви програли !')

 elif user_choice == 'Папір' and computer_choice == 'Камінь':
  user_score += 1
  print('Ви перемогли !')

 elif user_choice == 'Ножниці' and computer_choice == 'Камінь':
  computer_score += 1
  print('Ви програли !')

 elif user_choice == 'Ножниці' and computer_choice == 'Папір':
  user_score += 1
  print('Ви перемогли !')

 elif user_choice == computer_choice:
   print('Нічия !')

 else:
   print('Неправильне введення. Перевірте написання слова.')

break

print('Користувач : ' + str(user_score)+ ' |----| ' + 'Комп\'ютер : ' + str(computer_score))
```

So I have a problem, I just wrote whis program 'Rock Paper Scissors' (and I know its simple and you might even laugh at me, but Im just starting out) and I don`t know how to make it play few times. I run it choose one of the items and I get a score and program closes. how to loop it maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following structure (translated into English for others):

```
import random

choices = ['Rock' , 'Paper' , 'Scissors']
computer_score = 0
user_score = 0

game = True
while game:
    user_choice = input('Choose : Rock, Scissors, or Paper : \nYour choice : ')
    computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
    print('Computer chose : ' + computer_choice)

    if user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Paper':
        computer_score += 1
        print('You lost !')
    elif user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Scissors':
        user_score += 1
        print('You won !')

    # Other choices...

    game = (input('Play again? (y/n)\n') == 'y')

print('User : ' + str(user_score)+ ' |----| ' + 'Computer : ' + str(computer_score))
```

`game` is now by default `True` which can change if the user decides they don't want to play and input `n` after a given game. They keep playing by inputting `y` instead. The user and computer choices are now moved inside the while loop (to have a set of choices per game). The score is cumulative and displays at the end, once the user decided not to play again (though that's just a matter of how you want your game to work).

Note that you need to remove the `break` statement from the while loop (assuming the indentation in the OP was wrong and the `break` was part of the `while`). The only components of your original code between the first `if` for choices and the check if user wants to keep on playing should be the other choices (including the `else` for an unknown choice).

Comment: It works any number of times for me. Did you input `y` every time?

Comment: @СтепанБандера - did you remove the break statement? :) See my edit.

Comment: yes I did put y and Ive removed break, but it doesn`t seem to work

Comment: maybe I dont get how to input y ? just press it and click enter ?

Comment: @СтепанБандера exactly :) - just input and press enter. The break would matter only if it was inside the while and that would give you just 1 game anyway. Note that this is your whole program + the additional choices that I skipped.

Comment: the thing is : I input y and press enter and lets say I picked rock and pc picked paper, it won. when I press enter it just repeats that it has won

Comment: this is what I get: Play again? (y/n)
y
Нічия !
Play again? (y/n)
Папір
Користувач : 0 |----| Комп'ютер : 0

Comment: sorry, its working perfectly, I forgot to move computer_choice and user_choice to while loop, thanks for help, greatly appericated !! :)

Comment: Great :) I was suspecting something like that, but it's hard to know without seeing what you're running ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use recursion, but you need to add a case when the recursion should top, otherwise you will eventually run out of memory.

```
def start() :
   ~~~~~~~~~~~ bla bla bla ~~~~~~
   start()

start()
```

Comment: yes it worked) but not how i wanted, it just says score after one try infinite times